# Proper Place to Put Definition of Templated Class Definition

Tags: c++

Is it proper to define your class outside of the pound defines for a class or do they go inside the pound defines? Examples of what I am asking can be seen below.

```
#ifndef CLASS
#define CLASS

template <typename T>
Class 
{
    Class();
};

template <typename T>
Class::Class()
{
}

#endif
```

---Or--

```
#ifndef CLASS
#define CLASS

template <typename T>
Class 
{
    Class();
};

#endif

template <typename T>
Class::Class()
{
}
```

Comment: Neither, just define it in the class definition. Less duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would define it within the include guards (pound defines) to avoid multiply defined symbols.  So for template classes, as in your example, I would always define it within the include guards since they always have to be defined in header files.

For other non-template classes I might define member functions in a source (.cpp) file, so this would obviously be outside the include guards.

As a footnote I'd also point out that for such a simple constructor I'd actually define it within the class declaration, or even not define it at all, but I'm guessing your actual code is a little more complex than the example given.

Comment: And with C++11 one could simply say `MyCtor() = default;` :)